# Vuejs array rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vuejs for my project and I want to display a array.
This is the data :

```js
data() {
  return {
  people: [
      {"name": "Emily","properties": ["nice","good"]},
      {"name": "John","properties": ["bad","not good"]}
    ]
  }
}
```

So I want that this data should be displayed like this :

```html
<ul>
  <li>Emily : <p>- nice</p><p>- good</p></li>
  <li>John : <p>- bad</p><p>- not good</p></li>
</ul>
```

And my question is how can I do this in Vuejs dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for):

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(person, i) in people" :key="i">{{ person.name }} : 
      <p v-for="(property, j) in person.properties" :key="j">- {{ property }}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The second values in each v-for, `i` and `j` are the index of the current element.  We're specifically using it here to bind to the `key` property, which helps prevent rendering issues.

Hope this helps!